# How to select multiple date ranges from Fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to make a calendar feature in which a user can block off multiple date ranges by just selecting the start and end dates. I was thinking of using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) but I am not sure how to proceed with this.

I did see some examples of how to block some dates from being selected by adding my check on `dayClick` but these do not deal with date ranges. I would appreciate any help, I am not really looking for an entire source but some suggestions on how to go about this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a multi-part problem. Here's the basic idea.

- Allow the user to make a click+drag selection with [`selectable: true`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectable/)
- In the [`select`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) callback, add a [background event](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) with [`addEventSource`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/).
- When adding the event, give it a custom property: `block: true`.
- Use a custom function for [`selectOverlap`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectOverlap/) that returns false if event.block.

Something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/qp6Lxshp/4/).

```
selectable: true,
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
        start: start,
        end: end,
        rendering: 'background',
        block: true,
    }, ]);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
},
selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return ! event.block;
}
```

Background events are optional, but this is usually desired (visually).

If dragging and dropping already created events  is desired, you can use the  `selectOverlap` function in [`eventOverlap`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/) as well.

Comment: I was just going to post the top part, but then I realised I already had a fiddle that was only missing like 3 lines.

Comment: If I may ask, I just tried adding `unselect: true` to let users unselect date ranges, it is not recognizing that. Do we have to pass a callback of some kind?

Comment: I'm still new to FullCalendar and I'm pouring over the docs. But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `unselect` doesn't take a boolean. There is an unselect callback and method: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/ . Neither let the user unselect a date range. The callback is called *when* the selection is canceled and the method cancels the selection.

Comment: If you want a user to be able to destroy a selection after it's made, use eventClick. If you want them to be able to "drag holes" in the previous selection, this isn't trivial.

Comment: Yeah found that out :) 
I will probably just let them destroy a selection.

Comment: Note: eventClick won't be triggered for background events (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)

Comment: eventClick and dayClick won't triggered :(