# Select multiple days and unselect in full calendar jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net web application, in which I'm using FullCalendar.

I'm getting the calendar, but how can I select multiple dates and unselect selected dates?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<div id=availableSchedule"></div>
<script src="../../Resource/Javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../../Resource/Javascript/full-calendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    //$('#availableSchedule').parent().show();
    //$('#availableSchedule').html("");
    var calendar = $('#availableSchedule').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        eventClick: function (callEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            alert(callEvent.start);
        },
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            alert(callEvent.start+'2');
        },
        editable: true,

    });
</script>
```

Can any one please help me?

Comment: ..please post a proper code first

Comment: As for the first part of your question (selecting multiple dates), this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181823/how-to-select-multiple-date-ranges-from-fullcalendar