# FullCalendar clear selected days

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to create a calendar that lets users select multiple days then create an event based on the selected days and also clear the selected days.

So far, I am able to select multiple days (Thanks to [code from DanielST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29212500/9360197)) and get the selected days. Now I want to implement a 'Refresh' button to clear currently selected days. However, I was not able to implement it yet. I have tried ('refetchEvents') and ('rerenderEvents'), but it is not working.

How do I achieve it?

JS ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cm7yLj9q/)):

```
window.selectedDates = [];
window.batchEvents = [];
window.batchIDs = [];

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2014-11-10',
  defaultView: 'month',
  events: [{
    start: '2014-11-12T13:00:00',
    end: '2014-11-12T16:00:00',
  }, ],
  selectable: true,
  select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    let startDate = start.format();
    console.log('start: ' + startDate);
    let newID = randomIntFromInterval(0,100);
    window.batchIDs.push({id:newID});
    let newEventSource = {
        id: newID,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      rendering: 'background',
      block: true,
    };
    window.batchEvents.push(newEventSource);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [newEventSource]);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    window.selectedDates.push(startDate);
  },
  selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return !event.block;
  },
  unselectAuto: true,
  unselect: function(jsEvent,view) {
    //console.log(jsEvent);
  },
  customButtons: {
    refreshbutton: {
      text: 'refresh',
      click: function () {
        console.log('refresh clicked');
        console.log(window.batchEvents);        
        console.log(window.batchIDs);

        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEventSources',window.batchEvents);
        window.selectedDates = [];
        window.batchIds = [];
      }
    },
    selectedButton: {
      text: 'Check Days',
      click: function () {
        console.log(window.selectedDates);
        console.log(window.batchEvents);
      }
    }
  },
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today refreshbutton selectedButton',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  }
});
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

Comment: Just refreshing the events won't change them or remove anything. you'd need to remove all the event sources created during the `select` callbacks. For that you need to give those event sources IDs and keep a list of them. Then you can use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/removeEventSources to remove them.

Comment: @ADyson Hi thanks for the reply, but I'm talking about clearing selected days (e.g when I click on a day or hold and selecting days on the calendar). On the JSFiddle, the selected days are marked by green color. I want the user to be able to clear/reset them.

Comment: I know exactly what you're talking about. If you look at the code, those "selections" are actually added by creating an event source containing a background event (just as it describes in the link you provided). Therefore, to clear them you need to remove those event sources. (Personally I think it would have made more sense to declare _one_ event source when the calendar is initialised and put all the selection events within that, but that's another story.)

Comment: @ADyson Ah I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Then how do I get the id from the "selections"? From the [doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/select-callback), it has only start,end,jsEvent and view. I'm trying to get the id from the jsEvent but I could not get it.

Comment: The jsEvent has nothing to do with it. You need to _create_ the ID when you run addEventSource. Currently your code doesn't generate one. It can be passed to fullCalendar as part of the event source object (please check the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-source-object) Then you need to keep a record of it in an array of IDs. Then you re-use that array when you want to clear the selections, because you can pass that direct to the removeEventSources function.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for the explanation! It's much more clearer now. I have tried 'removeEventSources' shortly with an array of ID or Event Source Object, but strangely it does not work. I will try again later and get back to you.

Comment: Ok. Please update the question with your latest code if you are still stuck.

Comment: @ADyson I have updated my code. I have tried with `.fullCalendar('removeEventSources',window.batchEvents);` and `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEventSources',window.batchIDs);`. None of them worked. I have also tried with array of number (ID) as well. I have no idea how _optionalSourcesArray_ should look like.

Comment: `I have no idea how optionalSourcesArray`...well the documentation explains it can be an array of IDs or event sources. But you're putting the IDs _and_ the event sources into it. Get rid of `window.batchEvents.push(newEventSource);` and try again. Also `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [newEventSource]);` should be `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', newEventSource);` as far as I can see. Not sure why you wrapped that in an array.

Comment: P.S. using a random value as the ID is a bad idea- you could easily get duplicates. Just use a counter and keep incrementing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237220/discussion-between-user2018-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The problem is that `newEventSource` is badly named...it's not really an event **source** - it's just an **event**! That's why you have to put it inside an array when you run `addEventSource` - it's actually describing one individual event within the source, and `addEventSource` will accept an array of events as input, without any of the other event source properties.

So if we treat it as an event, and add/remove it using the `addEvent` and `removeEvents` functions, it works properly:

```
var selectedDates = [];
var batchIDs = [];
var id = 1;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2014-11-10',
  defaultView: 'month',
  events: [{
    start: '2014-11-12T13:00:00',
    end: '2014-11-12T16:00:00',
  }, ],
  selectable: true,
  select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    let startDate = start.format();
    let newID = id;
    id++;
    console.log('start: ' + startDate, "id: " + newID);
    let newEvent = {
      id: newID,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      rendering: 'background',
      block: true,
    };
    batchIDs.push(newID);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    selectedDates.push(startDate);
  },
  selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return !event.block;
  },
  unselectAuto: true,
  unselect: function(jsEvent, view) {
    //console.log(jsEvent);
  },
  customButtons: {
    refreshbutton: {
      text: 'refresh',
      click: function() {
        console.log('refresh clicked');
        console.log(batchIDs);

        for (var id = 0; id < batchIDs.length; id++)
        {
          console.log(batchIDs[id]);
          $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', batchIDs[id]);
        }
        selectedDates = [];
      }
    },
    selectedButton: {
      text: 'Check Days',
      click: function() {
        console.log(selectedDates);
      }
    }
  },
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today refreshbutton selectedButton',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/49mor6Lj/3/

For anyone interested here is the same concept implemented in the (at the time of writing) latest version 5 of fullCalendar: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GREQeJL

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help! I really appreciate it.